# In Android 4.0 Navigation Bar hijack first touch event

Tags: android, touch-event, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In Android 4.0 on devices without hardware navigation keys, Android will render navigation bar.

You can hide it, if you want by using `setSystemUiVisibility()`.

If that is done, lets say if you want to get as much screen as possible for playback, when you first touch screen (and yes, on `View` you implement `View.onTouchEvent()`), first touch will be hijacked by Android and your API will not be called. Only once navigation bar is visible it will be called.

Now, that can be avoided by also listening to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

and when navigation bar is visible just do what you will do on first touch.

Is there any other way to do the same, that will say Android 4.0 to propagate touch event to my app once Navigation bar is done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ICS you need to use listener.

Comment: Could you explain this?

Answer (score 2):

No, the system always consumes the first touch that brings the navigation bar back. You should only hide the navigation bar if your app is in a non-interactive state such as video playback.

Comment: That is not what it was asked. And answer is that there is no way to do it any other way than using listener as I explained in question. It works well, but I still believe it was a wrong design decision by Android team.